# when should I use query vs eval on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I used to perform operations such as `df.query("a > 10")` and they work fine.

However, I noticed that when I tried `df.query("(a + b) / 2 > 10")`, it failed.

Fortunately, when I tried `df.eval("(a + b) / 2 > 10")`, it works fine.

This leads me to the question what makes eval different from query and when should we use one vs the other?

Comment: You can do `df.eval("(a + b) / 2 "), and you will see the different

Comment: Here's a useful link: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html

Answer (score 12):

The `df.query` is to get the selected rows (where condition is fulfilled) and `df.eval` is to get boolean output for each row.
e.g.

```
df123 = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 6),
                      'B': range(10, 0, -2),
                      'C C': range(10, 5, -1)})
print(df123)
```

> ```
>    A   B  C C
> 0  1  10   10
> 1  2   8    9
> 2  3   6    8
> 3  4   4    7
> 4  5   2    6
> ```

```
df123.query('A > B')
```

> ```
>   A   B   C C
> 4 5   2   6
> ```

```
df123.eval('A > B')
```

> ```
> 0    False
> 1    False
> 2    False
> 3    False
> 4     True
> dtype: bool
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't really help since you can do: `df123[df123.eval('A > B')]` to obtain the same result as with query